# How would I use vectors for this geometry problem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider a quadrilateral ABCD.  K, L, M, N are the midpoints
of the segments AB, BC, CD, DA respectively. O is the intersection point of LN, KM. Let P and Q be the middle points of the diagonals AC and BD respectively. Show that O is the midpoint of the PQ.

I am running into trouble with trying to describe the intersection of LN and KM using vectors.  Is there an easier method that doesnt even use vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint: The point $O$ can be written in two ways: Since $O$ is the intersection of the two lines $L\vee N$ and $K\vee M$ there are uniquely determined $s$, $t\in[0,1]$ such that
$$O=(1-s){A+B\over2}+s{C+D\over2}=(1-t){B+C\over2}+t{D+A\over2}\ .$$
Here $s$ and $t$ can immediately be guessed.

Comment: Clever!  so s=t=1/2.  How do we know that they are uniquely determined?

Comment: Oh. nevermind. It makes sense why they are uniquely determined

Comment: $(1-\lambda) P + \lambda Q$ is the line segment between $P$ and $Q$ parameterized by $\lambda\in [0,1]$. There are $0$, $1$ or infinite many common points between two lines. In this case, flat, non-zero area, there should be one.